# How do I query for a player_id in this MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Here's an example document I have in my Mongo database:

```
    "sport" : "NBA",
    "team_id" : 111,
    "season_year" : 2013,
    "season_type" : "Regular",
    "title" : "2013-2014 Oklahoma City Thunder Individual Stats",
    "team_name" : "Oklahoma City Thunder",
    "players" : [
        {
            "player" : {
                "player_id" : 1293,
                "player_name" : "K.Durant",
                "games_played" : 50,
                "minutes_played" : 1900,
                "points_per_game" : 31,
                "rebounds_per_game" : 7.7,
                "assists_per_game" : 5.3,
                "offensive_rebounds" : 39,
                "defensive_rebounds" : 344,
                "total_rebounds" : 383,
                "assists" : 267,
                "steals" : 74,
                "blocks" : 41,
                "turnovers" : 172,
                "personal_fouls" : 110,
                "field_goals_made" : 507,
                "field_goals_attempted" : 989,
                "field_goal_percentage" : 0.513,
                "three_points_made" : 110,
                "three_points_attempted" : 264,
                "three_point_percentage" : 0.417,
                "free_throws_made" : 426,
                "free_throws_attempted" : 483,
                "free_throw_percentage" : 0.882,
                "points" : 1550,
                "highest_points" : 54
            }
        },
        {
            "player" : {
                "player_id" : 1515,
                "player_name" : "R.Westbrook",
                "games_played" : 25,
                "minutes_played" : 821,
                "points_per_game" : 21.3,
                "rebounds_per_game" : 6,
                "assists_per_game" : 7,
                "offensive_rebounds" : 27,
                "defensive_rebounds" : 122,
                "total_rebounds" : 149,
                "assists" : 174,
                "steals" : 44,
                "blocks" : 3,
                "turnovers" : 100,
                "personal_fouls" : 53,
                "field_goals_made" : 190,
                "field_goals_attempted" : 448,
                "field_goal_percentage" : 0.424,
                "three_points_made" : 34,
                "three_points_attempted" : 110,
                "three_point_percentage" : 0.309,
                "free_throws_made" : 119,
                "free_throws_attempted" : 150,
                "free_throw_percentage" : 0.793,
                "points" : 533,
                "highest_points" : 34
            }
        }
   ]
```

Using the JavaScript Mongo shell or Mongoid, how does one query to get the player hash that contains for example, `player_id: 1293`?

The thing is I have a collection with documents like this for each team in the NBA. I want to be able to build a user interface that allows you to query for an individual player as well. Would be nice to not have to query for the team then filter the array and be able to search the players array of every team instead; there should be a way to index this to speed up lookup times (storage is not an issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`$elemMatch` projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/):

```
db.teams.find(
    // find the document that contains said player:
    {"players.player.player_id" : 1293}, 
    // project so you only get the requested player:
    {"players" : {$elemMatch : { "player.player_id" : 1293  } }}).pretty();
```

You can put an index on `players.player.player_id`.

result:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52f3c81dae88ee90c711184b"),
        "players" : [
                {
                        "player" : {
                                "player_id" : 1293,
                                "player_name" : "K.Durant",
                                // etc.
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Note that this preserves the original structure of the document, which is quite helpful when mapping to strongly typed languages, but usually not what SQL-experienced people expect.

Oh, and maybe it makes sense to remove the extra `player` field in the players array? As long as the members of that array don't have additional fields, it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is dot notation. The query would be the following:

```
db.sport.find( { "players.player.player_id" : "1293" } )
```

However, this will return the entire document for the team. If you would like to pull just the sub-document for the player, you will need to use the aggregation framework and unwrap the players array.

The query would then be something like the following:

```
db.sport.aggregate( [
 { "$unwind" : "$players" },
 { "$match" : { "players.player.player_id" : 1293 } }
])
```